# Add checkboxes to the graph in plot_ly and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly

I have the following working example:

```
    library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
# shared data object
shared_us <- SharedData$new(mtcars, key = ~cyl)

# scatterplot of housing price index against homeownership
p17 <- shared_us %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~mpg, y = ~hp, color = ~gear, height = 400) %>%
  add_markers()

# add a column of checkboxes for region to the left of the plot
bscols(widths = c(3, NA),
  filter_checkbox(id = "cyl", label = "Region", sharedData = shared_us, group = ~cyl),
  p17
)
```

However, I produce the following:
[image]

I want to rewrite the code so that:

- All checkboxes are selected by default ( or one of them)

Comment: I know I can do it in shiny, but I want to do it this way so that I can knit to HTML and see it without publishing the file